# TEnsorflow 2.1.0 TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I am facing an error while importing tensorflow-2.1.0 with Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.

Name: protobuf
Version: 3.11.3

Following errors appeared

```
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.926212 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372] mod_wsgi (pid=5520): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/testnig/service.wsgi'.
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927298 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927347 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/service.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927352 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from service import app as application
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927358 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/service.py", line 11, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927362 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     import classify
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927367 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/classify.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927370 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     import tensorflow as tf
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927376 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927379 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from tensorflow_core import *
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927384 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927388 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from . _api.v2 import audio
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927393 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927397 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927402 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 11, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927406 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from tensorflow.python.eager import context as _context
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927411 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py", line 29, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927414 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927420 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/protobuf/config_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927423 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from tensorflow.core.framework import cost_graph_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_cost__graph__pb2
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927436 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/cost_graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927440 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927445 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]   File "/var/www/testnig/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 23, in <module>
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927449 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote 127.0.0.1:34372]     serialized_pb=_b('\\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\\x12\\ntensorflow\\"z\\n\\x10TensorShapeProto\\x12-\\n\\x03\\x64im\\x18\\x02 \\x03(\\x0b\\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\\x12\\x14\\n\\x0cunknown_rank\\x18\\x03 \\x01(\\x08\\x1a!\\n\\x03\\x44im\\x12\\x0c\\n\\x04size\\x18\\x01 \\x01(\\x03\\x12\\x0c\\n\\x04name\\x18\\x02 \\x01(\\tBq\\n\\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\\x11TensorShapeProtosP\\x01Z=github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/framework\\xf8\\x01\\x01\\x62\\x06proto3')
[Mon Feb 24 11:44:52.927464 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5520:tid 140127778391808] [remote **127.0.0.1:34372] TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument *emphasized text*'serialized_options'**
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you provide the data and especially the code used to generate this error as per a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                                                                        Please follow the steps.   1. In Ubuntu 18, install python 3.6 and create a Virtualenv. 2. pip3 install tensorflow  3. Clone or Download GIT --> https://github.com/minto5050/NSFW-detection  4. python3 classify.py test_image.jpg.. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: ^this should be in the question, not as a comment

Comment: Ok.. And one more information... I tried with Tensorflow version 1.8, 2.0. All of them giving same error..